# Combine CSV files according to shared values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV files, the first with students' IDs and their grades (different rows for each grade - for example the student with the ID `123` has grades in math, history and cs so there will be three lines with ID `123`), the second one is with students' names and their IDs. I want to create a new CSV file with names and grades.

I am working with python.

I tried to run double `for` loops but I guess it's wrong and I can't find something similar.

I think it should be something like:

```py
for i, row in id_grades.itterows():
    for j, row2 in id_names.irrerows():  
        # what shuld be here?
```

Comment: what do you mean by different row for each grade?

Comment: student with id 123 has grades in math,history and cs so there are three rows with id 123

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for a merge. You can achieve that with [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['id'], how = 'left')
del merged['id']
```

You should now see something like:

```
   grades  name
0      90   sam
1      90   sam
2      81   sam
3      82  jess
4      85  jess
5      96  jess
```

Comment: it works!! thnk you. if I would like to do it with for loop, how it would look like?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary with id's and names and just replace every id (in the first csv) using that dictionary.